# SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have somethink in my PostgreSQL insert request that's not correct.
When I execute:

```
INSERT  INTO data
        ( Email ,
          Email_MD5 ,
          Date_In ,
          Tel_mobile ,
          Tel_fixe ,
          Gender ,
          Title ,
          FirstName ,
          LastName ,
          DateOfBirth ,
          YearOfBirth ,
          AgeGroupe ,
          Adresse_1 ,
          Adresse_2 ,
          CP ,
          Ville ,
          Domain ,
          Groupe_Domaine ,
          Last_Date_R ,
          Last_Date_O ,
          Last_Date_C ,
          Pression ,
          Activity ,
          R
        )
VALUES  ( "000090@voila.fr" ,
          "b6ffc0c54f2c35866c4ccc4a7218472c" ,
          NULL ,
          "" ,
          "5789332" ,
          "MLLE" ,
          "" ,
          "Lydia" ,
          "Le Port" ,
          NULL ,
          NULL ,
          "26 - 35" ,
          "56" ,
          "56" ,
          "56400" ,
          "AURAY" ,
          "Bretagne" ,
          "" ,
          NULL ,
          NULL ,
          NULL ,
          "" ,
          "" ,
          ""
        );
```

PostgreSQL said:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERREUR: 
     identifiant délimité de longueur nulle sur ou près de « "" » LINE 5: "", ^
(Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "")
```

I don't understand why ? Is "" incorrect ?

Comment: is `Date_IN` nullable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Double quotes (`"`) are used for identifiers. Use single quotes (`'`) for values

```
VALUES('000090@voila.fr', ...
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS